# Exporting very large map to image in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, export, hydrology, png

I'm trying to use QGIS 3.10.14 to create a hydrological map to edit (as a PNG) in image editing software. My purpose is recreational.

I've paired the [Copernicus EU-hydro river network](https://land.copernicus.eu/imagery-in-situ/eu-hydro/eu-hydro-river-network-database?tab=mapview) with ESRI satellite imagery to create something which I hope I can trace to make a nice looking map with stream orders and such at 1:250k scale and 254 dpi resolution. Because it is most of Europe I'm talking about, that amounts to a very large image. I've been testing some different export settings with parts of Great Britain and Ireland, but I can only set the image size so high before the program crashes and the export fails. I've tried exporting in 'chunks' instead, but it seems that QGIS re-projects each  chunk with each export, thereby preventing me from matching them up and layering them atop one another in post.

Have I just reached the limits of my PC's processing power, or is there another way I can get this to work?

Could I somehow split the giant GIS map into a mosaic to piece back together?

Comment: 1:250,000 as a scale for a Europe-wide (3000 km width, Lisbon to Bucharest) map would result in a image width of 1200 cm. A square map of this size at 254dpi would contain about 14.4 billion pixels - does this answer your question, why the export doesn't work? It also should make you realize you chose the wrong scale for a Europe-wide map.

Comment: Could it still work, hypothetically, if it was assembled from separate chunks?

Comment: Have a look at the atlas functionality, it  will let you export your map as several part. (you will need to create a grid, choose a cell size that will result in exportable map)

Comment: That looks complicated. From the videos I've seen, it looks like it scales relative to features though, I don't want that.